# Singleton in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neural-network, singleton

I'm creating a simple Rails 5 app. The goal of the app is to use a statistical model to do simple predictions and display them.

I have a `Statistics` class (Plain Ruby class) that holds a neural network as an instance @attribute to make my predictions.

There should only be one instance of the `Statistics` class, so I used the `singleton` mixin:

```
require 'singleton'

class Statistics
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    @neuralnet = NeuralNet.new
  end

  def make_prediction(input)
    @neuralnet.make_prediction(input)
  end

  def train_model(data)
    @neuralnet.train(data)
  end

  ...

end
```

And from `config/initializers/Statistics.rb` my intention is to initialize the neural network when the app initializes itself, since the model needs to be trained with data to make predictions. I call the Statistics singleton instance from there.

```
# CSV reading and data importing to obtain training_data

Statistics.instance.train_model(training_data)
```

And then I try to use the trained instance from a controller, like so:

```
@prediction = Statistics.instance.make_prediction(input)
```

The prediction is good the first time the app loads the page. If I try to make another prediction, it fails miserably. I printed the `object_id` and discovered the `@neuralnet` ID changes after every page load, so basically my understanding is that the singleton is not working and I'm getting a fresh new, untrained model every time I try to make a new prediction.

It's really frustrating. Please help me out, I don't know if my understanding of the Singleton behavior is correct or if I should be using singletons at all. I just need a single instance of my trained neural net and call it from my controller... how can I accomplish that?

Comment: Do you change code too between the attempts? That may cause rails to reload your model file (and reinitialize the singleton, as a consequence)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev facepalm. I think that was it. I was changing the controller code to test the model. I was unaware Rails would reload my model file and cause the singleton to reinitialize. Pretty counter-intuitive, though, a singleton should be a singleton . I'll test a couple of things more, but that was probably it. Thank you sir.